# how to implement "suggest" query, with JavaClient in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to execute the following query with JavaClient.

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "my-suggestion-1": {
            "text": "sample",
            "completion": {
                "field": "suggest1",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could not find the document.

Please let me know the URL of the document.
Also, how should I implement it?

Someone, please lend me your wisdom.

## Environment

- Language: Java 8
- Framework: Spring
- Elasticsearch client (jar) ver

  - Org.elasticsearch: 5.1.1
  - Org.elasticsearch.client: 5.1.1
- Elasticsearch's ver: 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
TermSuggestionBuilder termSuggestionBuilder = SuggestBuilders.termSuggestion("field_name").text("my suggest terms");
client.prepareSearch("my_index").setSize(0).suggest(new SuggestBuilder().addSuggestion("foo", termSuggestionBuilder)).get();
```

A good thing to do is usually to check the Elasticsearch tests itself, like the [CompletionSuggestSearchIT](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/CompletionSuggestSearchIT.java)